# What is environment variable `locktt`?

Tags: maven, npm, environment-variables, optaplanner

I'm trying to build a [project](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering) with Maven.

Exactly as stated in the `README.adoc` file (command `mvn clean install -DskipTests -DskipITs` from PowerShell).

I am getting the following error:

> [ERROR] System variable locktt undefined
>   [ERROR] npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   [ERROR] npm ERR! errno 1
>   [ERROR] npm ERR! @ env: `SET "locktt"`
>   [ERROR] npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   [ERROR] npm ERR!
>   [ERROR] npm ERR! Failed at the @ env script.
>   [ERROR] npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

I did a quick search on the web, but I couldn't find anything about this `locktt` environment variable. Ask if you need more details about my system.

Comment: Thank you for reporting this "getting started" bug. It seems to be a customization in the `pom.xml` that doesn't work on all platforms. What operation system are you working on? We'll look into it.

Comment: I am working on Windows 10. Thank you very much for the interest in my question, by the way.

Comment: I confirm that on Ubuntu 18.04 the build works well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is caused by the following execution of `frontend-maven-plugin`:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
  <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>lock-treatment-tool execution</id>
      <phase>compile</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>npm</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <arguments>run env -- locktt</arguments>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This runs `npm run env -- locktt`, which is a hack to run a package's executable without adding a script in `package.json` and without using [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx).

> The [env script](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script.html) is a special built-in command that can be used to list environment variables that will be available to the script at runtime.

However, the actual command executed by npm's `env` script depends on the platform. For linux, it's [env](https://linux.die.net/man/1/env) and for Windows it's [SET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1). Linux's `env` allows the last argument to be a command that will be executed in the modified environment. This makes `npm run env -- locktt` work as a hack that executes `locktt` (on linux).

On Windows this fails because `SET` treats the argument differently. `SET locktt` means: display variables that begin with "locktt", which unsurprisingly fails with:

> [ERROR] System variable locktt undefined

Comment: In fact, I tried to build on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) and it worked. Thank you for the interest in my question!

Answer (score 1):

It's in your [pom](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-employee-rostering/blob/ab31342f61765651c08b464e1e648c642518d61e/employee-rostering-frontend/pom.xml) line 73. Maven tries to build it, but doesn't know what it is.

Comment: I have found this, thanks. Is it there a way to fix the problem?

Comment: checking it. I created that tool and added that line to the pom

Answer (score 1):

We found the windows use case and we open a JIRA for this

Being fixed by https://issues.jboss.org/browse/BXMSPROD-597
Top priority issue

Comment: Thank you very much, looking forward to the fix!